# Cypress can't find button in pop up modal

Tags: javascript, cypress, ui-automation

I have a test that requries me to login but I need to be able to dismiss the cookies prompt first. I have an ID for the button and it is always visisble yet Cypress can never find it, why?

```
 cy.visit('/signin')
 cy.get('button[id="save"]').click() // Dismiss cookies prompt
```

Here is the button HTML:

```
<button _ngcontent-kbm-c55="" mat-button="" id="save" class="mat-focus-indicator solo-button mat-button mat-button-base mat-raised-button" tabindex="0" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(128, 70, 241);"><span class="mat-button-wrapper"><div _ngcontent-kbm-c55="" class="action-wrapper" style="font-size: 14px;"><span _ngcontent-kbm-c55="">Accept all cookies</span></div></span><span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-button-ripple"></span><span class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></span></button>
```

Error:

```
Timed out retrying after 10000ms: Expected to find element: button[id="save"], but never found it.
```

[image: Cookie Promnpt]

Comment: What exactly is the error message fom Cyress? Is the modal visible in the browser of the test runner? Are you sure there is no other element with the id "save"?

Comment: If the banner sets a cookie, you can set that value prior to visiting the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are no shadow DOM's or Iframes you can use `contains` with the inner text of the button and click your button:

```js
cy.contains('Accept all cookies').click()
```

A more better approach would be to use a combination of selector and innertext.

```js
cy.contains('span', 'Accept all cookies').click()
```

In case of an iframe:

1. Install the [cypress-iframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-iframe) plugin
2. Add `import 'cypress-iframe';` in your `cypress/support/commands.js`
3. You can add in the test:

```js
cy.iframe('#frame-id').contains('Accept all cookies').click()
```

Comment: Oh, its a iframe, that explains why can't find so this approach won't work.

Comment: Updated the answer for iframe

Comment: ```Cannot set property message of [object DOMException] which has only a getter```

Comment: Requires ```"chromeWebSecurity": false``` in cypress.config. Thanks.